# Find all integers $n$ with the property that the sum of the decimal digits of $n^2$ equals $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I guess for starters what is even being referred to by "decimal digits" of an integer anyways? I'm assuming that it is asking for the sum of digits right?

If so, an observation is that if $n$ is 3-digits, then $n^2$ is 5-to-6 digits, which would mean that the sum of the digits of $n^2$ cannot equal $n$, as the max. the sum of the digits of $n^2$ would be $6*9 = 45$, while the smallest 3-digit integer is $100$.

Similarly, if $n$ is 2-digits, the max. of the sum of digits of $n^2$ is 4*9 = 36, so the max. of $n$ is 36.

So assuming the above is correct, I only need to check 36 integers, and include $-1$ to the values of $n$? Or is there a smarter way to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, you only need to check up to $36$, but what do you mean by "include $-1$"?

Comment: Ignore that, brain fart

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the sum of the digits of $(n^2) \equiv (n^2) \pmod{9}.$

This is because the above property holds for any integer, not just integers of the form $n^2.$

It is referred to as casting out 9's, re checking for divisibility by 9.

Therefore, you know that $n^2 \equiv n \pmod{9}.$  If $n$ is not a multiple of $9$, is this possible?

That is, under what circumstances does $9 | (n^2 - n) = (n)(n-1).$